# Django model history by date and datetime

Tags: python, django, django-simple-history

Assume I have model like this:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    balance = models.IntegerField()
    debt = models.IntegerField()
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

I'm using django-simple-history to get instance of the model as it would have existed at the provided date and time:

```
inst = Account.history.as_of(datetime.datetime.now().date)
```

It's working fine, but I want to get instance where balance field is represented as it would have existed at the provided date and time, and then debt field will be most recent of that date. I don't know if this is possible, didn't find anything about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The history ORM will return back a model based off of the one you submitted, as it existed at that point in time.

```
account = Account.objects.create(balance=1, debt=1)
account.save()
history_obj = account.history.last()
print(history_obj.debt)  # returns 1

account.debt = 222
account.save()
new_history_obj = account.history.last()
print(new_history_obj.debt)  # returns 222
```

Assuming you're using the Account.history.as_of() method to return the history object that you intend to be reading from, you could do this:

```
yesterday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
history_obj = Account.history.as_of(yesterday)
print(history_obj.debt)  # returns not the current debt, but the debt as-of yesterday
```

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're hoping to accomplish, you could just do this with what you have in your question:

```
inst = Account.history.as_of(datetime.datetime.now().date)
print(inst.debt)
```

Comment: Ok, but I want to get balance value as it existed on date and time and debt on date. Assume balance value is changing every hour, and debt is changing once a day. It all must be done with the same instance of model, because I have plenty of them, and then represent it in template

Comment: You should be able to grab any value you want from the HistoricalAccount object. You can do inst.debt and save that to a variable, you can do inst.balance and save that to a variable, or you could pass the whole inst object into a template and then do "Your balance at {{ date }} was {{ inst.balance}} and your debt was {{ inst.debt}}

Comment: This works as I want only for debt, but I get balance as it existed on that date and time, it must be the most recent of that day. I can call Account.history.most_recent(), then I get correct value, but it must be done in one instance only for that field, rest will be history.as_of('''some date and time for example")